# How to give two different templates for two models using Ruby on Rails Devise library

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am fairly new to Ruby on Rails, and have a problem working with the devise library. I have two models with the devise library, and they need to have different registration fields.

Currently the default template lives in the folder
    app/app/views/devise/registrations/.

but potentially I would like to have something like app/app/views/devise/registrations/model1/registration_template.rb, app/app/views/devise/registrations/model2/registration_template.rb

Right now I am not sure where this is handled. They don't even have to live in separate folders as long as I can use two different templates for the two models and have the app be directed to the correct templates for each model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Devise's readme:

> If you have more than one Devise model in your application (such as
>   User and Admin), you will notice that Devise uses the same views for
>   all models. Fortunately, Devise offers an easy way to customize views.
>   All you need to do is set `config.scoped_views = true` inside the
>   `config/initializers/devise.rb` file.
>
> After doing so, you will be able to have views based on the role like
>   `users/sessions/new` and `admins/sessions/new`. If no view is found within
>   the scope, Devise will use the default view at `devise/sessions/new`.
>   You can also use the generator to generate scoped views:
>
> `rails generate devise:views users`

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks! I actually referred to that first and it was still not working, but when I ran rails server again it did.